# Voltage-controlled current source design problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source

I am trying to design a voltage-controlled current source circuit. After some research, I decided to use an op-amp.

In the circuit shown below, when V1 is 0.3 V, then Vr is 0.3 V and the current is 0.3 A. These values are OK but when I use V1 is 2 V, Vr is 0.5 V.

What is wrong in this circuit? I also noticed that if I use a 12 V supply for the op-amp then there is no problem.

First:
[image]

Second:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input voltage is 2 volts and your current sense resistor (R3) is 1 Ω. This means you are trying to control the MOSFET at 2 amps. Then, if you look at the MOSFET's I-V characteristic from the [data sheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91019/irf530.pdf) you will see this (red-line by me at 2 amps): -

[image]

You should be able to see that you need a gate-source drive voltage of about 4.8 volts typically. Given that the source would need to be at 2 volts to make the circuit regulate, the gate voltage would need to be about 6.8 volts to barely satisfy regulation.

But, you have a 5 volt power rail and the op-amp cannot drive 6.8 volts. You need a higher voltage power supply or a MOSFET with a significantly lower \$V_{GS(THRESHOLD)}\$.

Comment: Does OP expect to deliver 2A from the MOSfet's drain? If so, then there's another problem...a 10-ohm load requires V3 to be 2V +4.5V + 20V, if drain current is 2A. For V3, a +12V DC supply is insufficient.

Comment: Good extra spot @glen_geek

Answer (score 2):

Look at the output of the opamp, better yet, look at the gate-source voltage. The IRF530 has a gate turn-on voltage around 5 volts. With the opamp power supply voltage set to 5 V, there isn't enough  voltage to turn on the FET. There are modern MOSFETs with lower turn-on voltage.